# How to use ArrayLists outside oncreate() method?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have multiple arraylists for different buttons in oncreate method and if i `setOnclicklistner` to each button inside `onCreate` then it works fine but when i try to make swtich case for button clicks, that is outside `onCreate` then i can't access arraylists.

I have implemented `View.onClickListner`.

here is `ArrayList` in `onCreate`

```
final ArrayList<String> unit1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            unit1.add("Exercise No 1");
            unit1.add("Exercise No 2");
            unit1.add("Exercise No 3");
```

and this the switch case for buttons outside `onCreate`, the reason its outside `onCreate` because there are other methods that affects onclick output.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA, unit1);
            break;
```

Comment: where you are declaring arrayList's  object? if you are declaring it in onCreate it will not work. Declare it Globally.

Comment: why cant you declare the Arraylist outside the onCreate, but initialize in the onCreate.  Make it a global variable but initialize it within the create function

Comment: Hey, are you setting the listener in the oncreate method. Provide some more detail so that i can answer u?

and did your arraylist is globally declared.

Comment: Dunno why people are saying "globally". It's called a class/member variable or field...

Comment: post your button click listener code

Comment: because i am talking about scope....

Comment: i was declaring them inside oncreate, declaring  them globally solved the issue, thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare it Globally.

For Example

```
public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity{
    ArrayList<String> unit1 = new ArrayList<String>();

@override    
     public void onCreate(Bundle saveonInstance){

      }
//now access it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
// declare array
 ArrayList<String> unit1 = new ArrayList<String>();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // load the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); 
   // fill array here
        unit1.add("Exercise No 1");
        unit1.add("Exercise No 2");
        unit1.add("Exercise No 3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ArrayList` variables as member variables of the activity

```
public class MainActivity{
private ArrayList<String> unit1;
.
.
}
```

In `onCreate` intialize the variable

```
unit1 = new ArrayList<String>();
unit1.add("Exercise No 1");
unit1.add("Exercise No 2");
unit1.add("Exercise No 3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare arraylist as a global variable
like

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//Add item to arraylist
list.add("Data 1");
}
```